# cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, lxml, python-docx

When I run linux azure function I get the error:
cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml'
I got these versions installed:

```
python-docx==0.8.11
lxml==4.9.3
```

I've tried different versions but no luck, works just fine locally on my pc.

Comment: Could you please share the error message and code.

Answer (score 0):

Use these Command in the file **" **init**.py"** to import **"etree"** from **"lxml"** module and **"Document"** from **"docx"** module:

```
from docx import Document
from lxml import etree
```

and **requirement.txt**:

```
Python-docx==0.8.11
lxml==4.9.3
```

[image]

I created a function named **test** and this is my simple code for testing purpose as shown below.

****init**.py :**

```
import logging
from docx import Document
from lxml import etree

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading('Testing Document', 0)
    p = document.add_paragraph('This pragraph is for testing purposes only. It contains nothing but some ')
    p.add_run('bold').bold = True
    p.add_run(' and some ')
    p.add_run('italic').italic = True
    p.add_run(' text.')
   
    document.save('demo.docx')
    
    document=Document('demo.docx')
    all_paras = document.paragraphs
    Alltext = []
    for para in all_paras:
        Alltext.append(para.text)
    xml_string = "<root><element>test</element></root>"
    root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"document has been saved: \n XML root is: {root[0].text} \n Documet is: {Alltext}")
```

These are my screenshots of the process and output as show below:

[image]

[image]

[image]